# Javascript/React (with Gulp/Babel) - can't import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jira

I'm developing a plugin for Atlassians JIRA system where I want to provide some advanced user controls.
I already tried around with implementing ES2015/Babel/Gulp which works - I can use ECMA6-functions with that build.
However, I also have several - already tested and validated - controls written in React available.

To start with something basic, I tried to reference an example and render it in my view.
However, I'm always getting "No React-DOM" in the browser (or "No React" if I'm trying to import it in my main script). What I'm missing here?

ReactTest.js (Excerpt, showing only some code)

```
import React from 'react';

let MNMLogo = 'http://www.mercurynewmedia.com/images/default-source/logos/mercury-logo-circle-201x201.png';

class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
    // React components are simple functions that take in props and state, and render HTML
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

export default SimpleExample;

The main script (from where I building the view)

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var buildPage = function (auiUserSelectOptions) {
    ...

    ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, document.getElementById("ReactTest"));
};
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {

},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
  "babel-register": "^6.24.0",
  "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
  "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
  "gulp-debug": "^3.1.0",
  "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
  "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
  "lazypipe": "^1.0.1",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "^6.9.0",
  "yarn": "^0.21.3"
},
```

My view "sucess.vm" (velocity template)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>$i18n.getText("wfenhance.library-management.title")</title>
    <meta name="decorator" content="atl.admin">
</head>
...

<div id="ReactTest"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify to be able to use `import` inside your application. Babel will indeed transpile `import` to `require` but a browser is not able to `require` modules.

My recommendation is to use Webpack as this is currently the most mature and popular bundler. You will also not need to use Gulp in this case.

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
  "watch": "webpack --progress --watch --display-error-details"
}
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1"    
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.24.0",
  "webpack": "^3.3.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "^6.9.0",
  "yarn": "^0.21.3"
},
...
```

webpack.config.js

*(I'm guessing your source files are inside `/src` and build output will go to `/build`)*

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["src/js/main.jsx"], // The main script entry
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
}
```

Start the project with `npm run watch`